# CGI-программа на С#

Tags: c#, html, iis, cgi

*Извиняюсь за неразборчивость, так как столкнулся с этим впервые и мало что в этом понимаю.*

Есть iis сервер, нужна html страница и  CGI-программа на С#, которая будет обрабатывать,например, какой-то написанный текст на странице- данным скриптом. Как всё это связать или где есть ресурс, который поможет разобраться? Где не искал- наталкивался на С/Phyton и другие языки, которые в данном случае мне не подходят.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/328638/ не читал, но `iis` `CGI` тат не упоминаются. ©Создание минимального ASP.NET Core веб-приложения с поддержкой npm, Webpack и TypeScript в Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Если вставить в IIS CGI обработчик, то можно послать на CGI - код запрос - но тогда вопрос меняется на "как вызвать из обработчика обработчик".

Comment: И момент 2, как именно в .asp или .cshtml или в .сs  вы собираетесь вставлять скрипты? Если в html - то тогда с# вам не нужен - решается надстройками IIS.

Comment: Может вопрос вовсе не в CGI а в том, как выводить данные на форму? Тогда почитайте что такое ASP и что такое NET-MVC. В с# чуть по другому реализовано связывание.

Comment: Если вопрос по АSP вам сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Comment: У меня уточнение - хотелось бы от автора вопроса услышать, а так ли нужен ему именно CGI? Может, вопрос в том, как при сабмите формы обработать запрос при помощи программы, написанной на C#? Тогда CGI выбрасываем из вопроса, и можно действительно, как советовали в комментариях выше, взять минимальный пример WEB - приложения на ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 1):

Как один из возможных вариантов вы можете создать консольное приложение и использовать Console.WriteLine для вывода в std_out. Информация об HTTP запросе хранится в переменных окружения. Поэтому для доступа к query_string и другим частям HTTP-запроса используйте Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable. Также не забудьте включить cgi_mode в IIS. Для разных версий IIS CGI настраивается немного по-разному, поэтому уточняйте в официальной документации для той версии, которую используете.

```
using System;
namespace CgiInCsharp
{
    class Cgi
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
            Console.Write("<html><head><title>CGI" + 
                " in C#</title></head><body>" +
                "CGI Environment:<br />");
            Console.Write("<table border = \"1\"><tbody><tr><td>The" + 
                " Common Gateway " +
                "Interface revision on the server:</td><td>" + 
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GATEWAY_INTERFACE") +
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("<tr><td>The serevr's hostname or IP address:</td><td>" +
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SERVER_NAME") + 
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("<tr><td>The name and" + 
                " version of the server software that" +
                " is answering the client request:</td><td>" +
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SERVER_SOFTWARE") +
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("<tr><td>The name and revision of the information " +
                "protocol the request came in with:</td><td>" +
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SERVER_PROTOCOL") +
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("<tr><td>The method with which the information request" +
                "was issued:</td><td>" +
                System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REQUEST_METHOD") +
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("<tr><td>Extra path information passed to a CGI" +
                " program:</td><td>" +
                System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH_INFO") + 
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("<tr><td>The translated version of the path given " +
                "by the variable PATH_INFO:</td><td>" +
                System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH_TRANSLATED") +
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("<tr><td>The GET information passed to the program. " +
                "It is appended to the URL with a \"?\":</td><td>" +
                System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("QUERY_STRING") +
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("<tr><td>The remote IP address of the user making +"
                "the request:</td><td>" +
                System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REMOTE_ADDR") +
                "</td></tr>");
            Console.Write("</tbody></table></body></html>");
        }  // End of Main().
    }  // End of Cgi class.
} // End of CgiInCsharp namespace.
```

Здесь есть пример реализации CGI-программы на C# для IIS.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9433/Understanding-CGI-with-C